# Nestjs validation pipe not working as expected when using @Param

Tags: parameters, controller, nestjs, class-validator

I have an endpoint that is using a restful url service/getDocument/:documentId 
I've setup a path object with validation on it and when the endpoint is called with a documentId all is good.  When I leave off the documentId I get a 404 error and it doesn't give me the message from the @IsNotEmpty message.  When I convert the endpoint to use @Query I get the message I'm expecting.

Service

```js
@Controller('service') // Define this class as a controller
export class Controller {
   constructor() {}

  // Gets all prescriptions with pagination
  @Get('getDocument/:documentId')
  async getDocument(
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Param() params: Path,
    @Headers() headers: Headers
  ): Promise<any> {
...
```

this is the message I get

```sh
    "message": "Cannot GET /service/getDocument/"
```

my path dto

```js
import { IsString, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class Path {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty({ message: 'documentId required in url as rest param <serviceURL>/<endpoint>/<documentId>' })
  @ApiModelProperty({
    required: true,
    description: 'document reference id'
  })
  documentId: string;
}
```

And when I convert my endpoint to use @Query I get the expected response. Status 422 and this message from the dto

Updated Controller

```js
@Get('getDocument')
   async getDocument(
    @Res() res: Response,
    @Query() params: Path,
    @Headers() headers: Headers
  ): Promise<any> {
```

Response

```sh
{
   "errors": [
        "documentId required in url as rest param <serviceURL>/<endpoint>/<documentId>",
        "documentId must be a string"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This may just be a type, but in your controllers you have you URL path defined as `/url/:documentId`, but in your errors the endpoint is at `service/getDocument/` which would explain the 404 if it is not a typo.

Comment: I changed those value just to post here and missed changing both places.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn’t validate parameters with ‘IsNotEmpty’. In your case, controller can’t handle empty documentId because of routing path ‘getDocument/:documentId’. You also shouldn’t validate it with ‘IsString’ - it’s always. But you may want to validate length, for example.